# How to clear Chromium Browser cache?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, chrome

I'm trying to clear my Chromium browser cache using `CLI` on `Gallium OS` (based on `Xubuntu`). What command should I use?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On Linux you can clear the browser cache using the following command, after closing the browser:

## Chromium

The browser cache is stored in different directories depending on whether Chromium is installed as a regular package or as a snap. Run

```
$ which chromium
```

to find out which one your system is using. Examples:

```
/usr/bin/chromium   -> traditional package
/snap/bin/chromium  -> snap
```

#### Installed from regular package

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/chromium
```

#### Installed from snap

```
rm -rf ~/snap/chromium/common/.cache/chromium
```

## Google Chrome

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/google-chrome
```

Comment: Hmm. On Ubuntu 20.04 installed from snap `~/snap/chromium/common/.cache/chromium` did not exist on my system.  So `rm -rf ~/snap/chromium/common/.cache` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the 'traditional package' for chromium,

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/chromium
```

is not enough to clear "everything". I noticed after running that command that cookies were indeed cleared but stored values for forms were still there and browser history was still there as well. The following clears those as well:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/chromium
```

That .config folder has a lot of different subfolders but after deletion and upon restarting chromium, they are all repopulated. So a complete command to clear everything in chromium is:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/chromium && rm -rf ~/.config/chromium
```

Yes, granted the OP did not ask for "everything" but if you are reading this question that is possibly what you might be trying to do.